# Why can't I call localhost localhost:5000 from localhost:3000 using fetch in react?

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

My react application running on `localhost:3000` and in that I am making a GET request in my code using fetch to `localhost:5000/users`.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setUsers(data))
}, []);
```

But I'm getting an error called

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/users' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: This is a cors error :)

Comment: try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a much discussed problem. Follow the steps below:

If you are using nodejs or express js for your backend. Install the `cors` package in your express app.

```
npm install cors
```

And, include the following in your `index.js` file.

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

That's it. It should work now. Don't forget to restart your node server.

To understand it better, read this [article](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS problem , Try to use with this way

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/users', { mode: 'no-cors' })
```

Comment: But with that, you won't be able to access the response, that is, `res => res.json()` would return `null`.

Comment: As I understood , you have using res.body , and it null , have you try with this way ? 

`fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/7819a548-3481-4e7e-bd74-0bec42a1421e', {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })`